# mouse clicks and keystrokes count clicked any where

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to implement a functionality in my mac application which will return me the mouse clicks and keystrokes count clicked any where (in my application or outside). Please guide me.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSEvent's `+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block` provides this functionality.

Here is a quick example:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask|NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *anEvent){

    if(anEvent.type==NSKeyDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Had key down event: %@",anEvent);
    }
    if(anEvent.type==NSLeftMouseDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Had left mouse down event: %@",anEvent);
    }
}];
```

You could add this somewhere during your apps initialization, for example in you application delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.

The above does **NOT** register events in your application, only in other applications. If you also need events in your app, you can add a local monitor (slightly different as it returns an event):

```
    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask|NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent *anEvent){

        if(anEvent.type==NSKeyDown)
        {
            NSLog(@"Had local key down event: %@",anEvent);
        }
        if(anEvent.type==NSLeftMouseDown)
        {
            NSLog(@"Had local left mouse down event: %@",anEvent);
        }

        return anEvent;
    }];
```

Also note that according to the NSEvent documentation: *Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see AXIsProcessTrusted).*

Comment: Will you please explain further. that will be very helpful. Thank you.